# ZURB Foundation Offcanvas works but nothing else

Tags: zurb-foundation

I just updated Foundation 5.0.3 with 5.2.1. For some reason, all javacripts no longer work with the exception of Offcanvas. I tried using using foundation.min.js and also loading each manually.

Has anyone else encounter this issue?

Comment: Please show us some of your code that doesn't work. Also what do you mean by `no longer works`?

Comment: @BeatAlex I reproduced the page at CodePen: [http://cdpn.io/DCvIt](http://cdpn.io/DCvIt). By no longer works, I mean that the scripts just stopped firing. I'm using Offcanvas, Orbit, Tooltip, and Dropdown from Foundation. All were working prior to updating the library (I've updated it a couple of times to make sure something didn't get corrupt during the transfer.) Only Offcanvas works now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The issue was with the stylesheet. I brought foundation.css into my own stylesheet as a scss file via CodeKit. The compression didn't play nice with Foundation's javascript library. I'm now just importing foundation.css without combining it with my stylesheet.I've never encountered this kind of issue. I learn something new everyday.